# Getting different values by passing Pointers to a function in Go

Tags: pointers, struct, go

Say I want to pass a pointer to a function and change the value of a struct which that pointer points to by doing so. I would normally do this by dereferencing the pointer:

```
type Test struct { Value int}
func main() {
   var i Test = Test {2}
   var p *Test = &i
   f(p)
   println(i.Value)  // 4
}
func f(p *Test) {
   *p = Test{4}
}
```

My question is, why this code doesn't change the value

```
type Test struct { Value int}
func main() {
   var i Test = Test {2}
   var p *Test = &i
   f(p)
   println(i.Value)  // 2
}
func f(p *Test) {
   // ?
   p = &Test{4}
}
```

while this one does:

```
type Test struct { Value int}
func main() {
   var i Test = Test {2}
   var p *Test = &i
   f(p)
   println(i.Value)  // 4
}
func f(p *Test) {
   p.Value = 4
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because this line:

```
p = &Test{4}
```

Just assigns a new pointer value to the `p` variable. Inside the `f()` function, `p` is just a local variable. By assigning any new value to `p`, you are just changing the value of the local variable and **not** the pointed value.

The `p` local variable in `f()` has nothing to do with the `p` local variable in `main()`. If you change `p` in `f()`, it will not change `p` in `main()` (and it won't change the pointed struct value either).

In your second example:

```
p.Value = 4
```

It is a shorthand for:

```
(*p).Value = 4
```

This changes the *pointed* value, hence you will observe the change when `f()` returns.

**Note:**

Just as a side note, if in your `main()` function you would pass the address of `p` (the local variable in `main()` which is a pointer) to function `f()`, you could modify the address stored in main's `p`:

```
func f(p **Test) {
    *p = &Test{4}
}
```

And from `main()`, call it like:

```
var i Test = Test{2}
var p *Test = &i
f(&p)
println(i.Value) // 2 - Note that 'i' won't change!
println(p.Value) // 4 - Only the address in 'p' to the new struct value created in f()
```

But obviously passing a single pointer `*Test` and modifying the pointed value (`p.Value = 4`) is more efficient, much more convenient and much cleaner.